# No Of Queries Hitting Redshift tables in a Time Frame

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How can I know the number of queries hitting a table in a particular time frame and what are those queries

Is it possible to get those stats for live tables hitting a redshift table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the number of queries hitting a redshift table in a certain time frame:

```
SELECT
count(*)
FROM stl_wlm_query w
  LEFT JOIN stl_query q
         ON q.query = w.query
        AND q.userid = w.userid
  join pg_user u  on u.usesysid = w.userid
-- Adjust your time frame accordignly
WHERE w.queue_start_time >=  '2022-04-04 10:00:00.000000'
AND   w.queue_start_time <=  '2022-04-05 22:00:00.000000'
AND   w.userid > 1
-- Set the table name here:
AND querytxt like '%my_main_table%';
```

If you need the actual queries text hitting the table in a certain timeframe, plus the queue and execution time and the user (remove if not needed):

```
SELECT
       u.usename,
       q.querytxt,
       w.queue_start_time,
       w.total_queue_time / 1000000 AS queue_seconds,
       w.total_exec_time / 1000000 exec_seconds
FROM stl_wlm_query w
  LEFT JOIN stl_query q
         ON q.query = w.query
        AND q.userid = w.userid
  join pg_user u  on u.usesysid = w.userid
-- Adjust your time frame accordignly
WHERE w.queue_start_time >=  '2022-04-04 10:00:00.000000'
AND   w.queue_start_time <=  '2022-04-05 22:00:00.000000'
AND   w.userid > 1
-- Set the table name here:
AND querytxt like '%my_main_table%'
ORDER BY w.queue_start_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "hitting a table you mean scan then they system table stl_scan lists all the accesses to a table and lists the query number that causes this scan.  By writing a query to aggregate the information in stl_scan you can look at it by time interval and/or originating query.  If this isn't what you mean you will need to clarify.

I don't understand what is meant by 'stats for live tables hitting a redshift table?'.  What is meant by a table hitting a table?

Comment: Yeah I think I meant this only let me look into it and get back to you. Also once I query this table , ill know what is the information that is stored in it

Comment: I did that so I got the data but it doesn't tell me which query was hitting my table.So lets suppose I have a table my_main_table and N nos of query are hitting the main table in a particular hour. I want to know what are those queries and how long does it take to execute them. Is Is possible to do so ?

Comment: Yes.  You will need to join information for stl_query (run time) and stl_querytext (full text of query).  The query number will be the same in all 3 tables but query numbers will repeat after a few days so you will need to have approximately the same time and date to be sure that you have the right info joined.

Comment: Okay let me try and look into it and see how can I get those numbers